# How do I authorize CognitoIdentityCredentials for my API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have a Serverless backend that implements AWS_IAM authorizer using the serverless framework.

My client is a React application. I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate users and AWS Federated Identities to retrieve temporary credentials for the user.

The user is assuming an IAM Role that has `APIGatewayInvokeFullAccess` policy attached. I then sign my request using [aws4](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) and make my request using `Axios`.

To my understanding, I am doing everything right. But, I am still receiving a 403 error on my client request. I even logged the tokens that are being retrieved to the console and used those tokens in postman. When I use postman, the error message says "The security token included in the request is invalid". I have read every doc and tried every possible solution, but I am still unable to debug this error. Any help at all would be incredible.

I am following this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/) for the application flow.

Comment: Which token are you passing with your calls. `idToken` or `accessToken` ?

Comment: accessId, secretAccessKey, and sessionToken